# Ubuntu One Limit Concurrent Uploads / Downloads

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I installed Ubuntu One Indicator, and it shows that several files are being uploaded at once. It seems my network is very sensitive to many open connections, and even when limiting the speed, the amount of connections Ubuntu One has made, causes latency spikes.

I was wondering if there were a way to limit how many files were being uploaded and downloaded at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you limit how many files are transferred (uploaded or downloaded) at once is by setting `simult_transfers` to something lower than the default of 10 in the `__main__` section of the `syncdaemon.conf` configuration file, and restarting syncdaemon.

You can edit the system configuration file, `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf`, or the user configuration file `~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` (or create a file there if one doesn't exist). I've found 3 is a good compromise value for when I'm on 3G; YMMV. If you don't have a user `syncdaemon.conf` and don't want to edit the system one, you'd want to create a file that looked like

```
[__main__]
simult_transfers = 3
```

If the file already exists, you just add the `simult_transfers` line without the section header.

Once that is done, you can restart syncdaemon by entering

```
u1sdtool -q; u1sdtool -c
```

in a terminal.