# Ubuntu One hangs router sockets

Tags: networking, ubuntu-one, router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Limit Concurrent Uploads / Downloads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97665/ubuntu-one-limit-concurrent-uploads-downloads)

I have Ubuntu One for kde in 12.04 kubuntu.
Every time I run it from scratch, e-mail and others stop working properly giving socks problems. That problems appear in all computers on the network and stop when I restart the router.

The problem only happens when U1 is syncronizing lots of files at the same time, so I supose I have a problem with a threshold of ports/sockets in my router.

Is there any way to limit them in Ubuntu One configuration? Could you put a maximum in the parameters section the same way you have an Upload/download limit?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider this question and its answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97665/ubuntu-one-limit-consecutive-uploads-downloads If it works, say and we'll close this as a duplicate.